# Can a bastion be assigned a specific AWS Elastic IP with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We need to whitelist some Elastic IPs from the corporate firewall as allowed destination IPs for SSH. Is there a way to configure a bastion instance with Terraform and assign it a specific Elastic IP? And, likewise, have it return that EIP to the provisioned pool when the bastion is destroyed? Obviously, we don't want EIPs to be deallocated from our AWS account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Terraform only supports attaching Elastic IPs to EC2 instances upon [EIP creation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/eip.html) when you can choose to optionally attach it to an instance or an Elastic Network Interface. [NAT Gateways](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/nat_gateway.html) currently allow you to associate an EIP with it upon the NAT Gateway being created but that's a slightly special case.

The [instance module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) itself only allows a boolean choice of whether the instance gets a normal public IP address or not. There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1273) around allowing instances to be associated with pre-existing EIPs but at the time of writing no pull request to support it.

If it's simply a case of wanting to open up a port on your corporate firewall once and not having to touch it for a bastion box that is torn down regularly and you're open to allowing Terraform to create and manage the EIP for you then you could do something like the following:

```
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami           = "ami-abcdef12"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags {
    Name = "bastion"
  }
}

output "bastion_id" {
  value = "${aws_instance.bastion.id}"
}
```

And in a separate folder altogether you could have your EIP definition and also lookup the outputted instance ID from a [remote state file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html) for the bastion host and use that when applying the EIP:

```
resource "terraform_remote_state" "remote_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "mybucketname"
    key    = "name_of_key_file"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "bastion_eip" {
  vpc      = true
  instance = "${terraform_remote_state.remote_state.output.bastion_id}"
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

In the above example I've used [@BMW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498256/bmw)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076669/2291321) so that you should get an error in any plan that attempts to destroy the EIP just as a fail safe.

This at least should allow you to use Terraform to build and destroy short lived instances but apply the same EIP to the instance each time so you don't have to change anything on your firewall.

A slightly simpler approach using just Terraform would be to put the EIP definition in the same `.tf` file/folder as the bastion instance but you would be unable to use Terraform to destroy anything in that folder (including the bastion instance itself) if you kept the `lifecycle` configuration block as it simply causes an error during the plan. Removing the block simply gets you back to destroying the EIP everytime you destroy the instance.

Comment: this answer is a great workaround, but now that Terraform supports it, it's probably better to create EIPs out of band and associate them using aws_eip_association. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Existing answer is outdated. Associating existing Elastic IPs is now possible thanks to this change: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/5236

Docs: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/eip_association.html

Excerpt:

> aws_eip_association
>
> Provides an AWS EIP Association as a top level
>   resource, to associate and disassociate Elastic IPs from AWS Instances
>   and Network Interfaces.
>
> NOTE: aws_eip_association is useful in scenarios where EIPs are either
>   pre-existing or distributed to customers or users and therefore cannot
>   be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time working through this problem and found the other answers helpful, but incomplete.

For those people trying to reallocate an AWS elastic IP using Terraform, we can do so using a combination of `terraform_remote_state` and the `aws_eip_association`. Let me explain.

We should use two separate root modules, themselves within a parent folder:

```
parent_folder
├--elasticip
|   └main.tf
└--server
    └main.tf
```

In `elasticip/main.tf` you can use the following code which will create an elastic IP, and store the state in a local backend so that you can access its output from the server module. The output variable name cannot be 'id', as this will clash with the remote state variable id and it will not work. Just use a different name, such as `eip_id`.

```
terraform {                                                                                                             
  backend "local" {                                                                                                     
    path = "../terraform-eip.tfstate"                                                                                   
  }                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                    
resource "aws_eip" "main" {
  vpc = true
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

output "eip_id" {
  value = "${aws_eip.main.id}"
}
```

Then in `server/main.tf` the following code will create a server and associate the elastic IP with it.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "eip" {
  backend = "local"

  config = {
    path = "../terraform-eip.tfstate"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
  allocation_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.eip.eip_id}"
  #For >= 0.12
  #allocation_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.eip.outputs.eip_id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "insert-your-AMI-ref"
}
```

With that all set up, you can go into the `elasticip` folder, run `terraform init`, and `terraform apply` to get your elastic IP. Then go into the `server` folder, and run the same two commands to get your server with its associated elastic IP. From within the server folder you can run `terraform destroy` and `terraform apply` and the new server will get the same elastic IP.

Answer (score 0):

> we don't want EIPs to be deallocated from our AWS account.

yes, you can block it. set `prevent_destroy` to true

```
resource "aws_eip" "bastion_eip" {
    count           = "${var.num_bastion}"
    lifecycle {
      prevent_destroy = true
    }
}
```

Regarding EIP assigned, please refer @ydaetskcoR's reply

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this today. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I may be missing it... how do I assign a specific ElasticIP to the bastion? Again, we have to whitelist some destination IPs so I need to assign a specific one to the bastion. I get how you're showing to prevent it from being deleted--which is also needed. But how do I assign a specific, pre-existing IP to the bastion?

Comment: I might be missing something but I think that only works for NAT gateways. [EC2 instances](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) don't have an `allocation_id` argument

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an autoscaling group you can do it in the user data. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=52601

```
#!/bin/bash
 
# configure AWS
aws configure set aws_access_key_id {MY_ACCESS_KEY}
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key {MY_SECRET_KEY}
aws configure set region {MY_REGION}
 
# associate Elastic IP
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
ALLOCATION_ID={MY_EIP_ALLOC_ID}
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOCATION_ID --allow-reassociation
```